# Android : GCM PendingIntent not working in Samsung note 2

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I can receive gcm notification in all the devices. But when i click the notification then it is not navigating to corresponding activity what I have given in the Intent. I did not set any flags for the Intent.

It's working fine in all other devices.

This is my code.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, NotificationActivity.class);
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmIntentService.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm)
                        .setContentTitle("New messages")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

My manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name="mellotv.com.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

I have checked the device api and it is 19.

Could some one help me to solve this problem?